# creating the controller in the index page while using routing in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have made an app using angularjs. I am using routing to load different page inside the index.html page and I have also made controller for every page that I have loaded inside the Index page. But I also want to create a controller for The index page to control the content of the index page. how should I do that ?

Comment: maybe you can add your code here. For example. in index.html you can add controller with ng-controller to any of the html tags

Comment: I tried it but It didnt worked

Comment: you can create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) to show what you have tried.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).